# nginx proxy_passing to wordpress website on a specific location

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am doing a WordPress website for my college assignment and have decided to host it myself on my home server as I am wanting to learn about server configuration etc. I want to be able to access this WordPress website via my domain as its required to be publicly accessible for grading, and I also want to host another WordPress website for a portfolio assignment. I want to be able to access these via a nginx reverse proxy and access the sites like this:

`jeremyruffell.com/WordPressSite1/ => Wordpress Site 1 hosted on 192.168.1.211:8081`
`jeremyruffell.com/WordPressSite2/ => Wordpress Site 2 hoisted on 192.168.1.211:8082`

p.s. I used WordPressSite1 & WordPressSite2 as a filler name as I don't know what I am calling my assignment sites.

I have tried referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205743/nginx-proxy-to-wordpress-website) question and had no luck.In my own attempt I tried just getting one of the two websites to work, Because if i can get one to work I can get two to work.

#### conf file

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location ^~ /WordPressSite1/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.211:8081/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

#### I also added this to the wp-config.php

```
/** set the site URL */
define('WP_HOME','http://192.168.1.211/WordPressSite1');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://192.168.1.211/WordPressSite1');

/** Fix to get the dashboard working with the reverse proxy.*/
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/",  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

I tried this code and I just get a infinite loop to my `/` locaiton block.

Any help would be much appreciated or pointed in the direction of were I can find the information to do this.

Thanks Heaps,