# how to NGINX Proxy to wordpress website blog.example.com to example.com/blog

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a statically served site (using nginx). I want to host a wordpress blog (hosted on a different instance) under /blog folder.

```
location ^~ /blog/ {
        rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://blog.example.com;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location ^~ /blog/wp-includes {
        proxy_pass https://blog.example.com/wp-includes;
    }

    location ^~ /blog/wp-login.php {
        proxy_pass https://blog.example.com/wp-login.php;
    }

    location ^~ /blog/wp-admin {
        proxy_pass https://blog.example.com/wp-admin;
    }
```

and the following wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://SOMESITE.com/blog/');
```

But it doesn't work, I follow [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205743/nginx-proxy-to-wordpress-website) also.

please help me out if any one have any solution
thanks in advance